# Customizing gmail for business

Tags: gmail, customization, google-apps

Is it possible to customize gmail landing page ? I am thinking of using gmail for business to manage my emails and wondering if one can include a link on his business website which directs to their work email account (gmail one) webpage featuring their business logo on it.

If not Google, does anybody provide such flexibility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want google for work:
https://www.google.com/work/

"With the exception of Google Apps Vault, all are included in the basic plan, which costs $5 per user per month or $50 per user per year. A premium package, Drive for Work, includes Google Apps Vault plus unlimited storage is available for $10 per user per month."

You will be able to customize the theme with logos of your choice.